# jQuery is not responding to the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to make some text slowly move down when I scroll down the page. However, my jQuery selector is not firing when I move down the page.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="stairsImage">
   <h1 id="testName">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div#main").scroll(function(){
      var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

      $(".testName").css({
        'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll/2 +'%)'
      });
   }) 
});
```

I am using Bootstrap if that makes a difference. 
I am sure it is something simple I am missing. Thank you.

Comment: Your selector is looking for a _class_ named "testName". I think you want `#testName` to find the `id` instead.

Comment: need help with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$("#testName").css({` since you're using `id`

Comment: I am so angry with myself. Thank you. I can't believe I looked over that. Sorry to waste everyones time.

Answer (score 0):

Change to $(window).scroll . . .